# django-environ and Postgres environment for docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, django-environ

I am using `django-environ` package for my Django project.
I provided the DB url in the `.env` file, which looks like this:
`DATABASE_URL=psql://dbuser:dbpassword@dbhost:dbport/dbname`

My DB settings in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db(),
}
```

So far, I have no issues.

Then, I created a `docker-compose.yml` where I specified that my project uses Postgres database, i.e.:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  ...
    db
      image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=???
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=???
      - POSTGRES_DB=???
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

Now I am confused a little.

How do I provide these `POSTGRES_*` env. variables there? Do I need to provide them as separate variables alongside with the `DATABASE_URL` in my `.env` file? If yes, what's the best way do accomplish this? I aim to avoid duplication in my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the vars in your .env file and then reference the file in the `env_file` attribute of Django container in docker-compose file. This is where the Django settings file can access them with `os.environ.get()`. Env vars in the `environment` attribute in a docker-compose file do not interpolate from an .env file. They would only interpolate there if the vars were exported in the shell that the compose file is run from. It helped me to view these docs when experiencing the same issue: [Environment variables precedence in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/).

.env file example:

```
DB_NAME=my_database
DB_USER=postgres_user
DB_PASSWORD=1234567
```

In Django block in docker-compose file, reference your env file:

```
# ....
    env_file:
      - ./.my_env_file
# ...
```

Django settings:

```
import os
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
           # ...

            "POSTGRES_DB": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
            "POSTGRES_USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD")

           # ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `django-environ` doesn't support variable expansion (as of v0.10.0), so the way I found is to spell out the individual options instead of using `env.db()`

Django settings

```py
DATABASES = {
  "default": {
     # ...
     "NAME": env("DB_NAME"),
     "USER": env("DB_USER"),
     "PASSWORD": env("DB_PASSWORD"),
  },
}
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  # ...
  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable expansion in your `.env` file. Something like

```
DB_NAME=dbname
DB_USER=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
DATABASE_URL=psql://$DB_USER:$DB_PASSWORD@dbhost:dbport/$DB_NAME
```

and then something like this in your compose file

```yaml
services:
  postgresdb:
    container_name: projectname_db
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
...
```

I am not exactly familiar with django-environ but this should work

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. It says `ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as '$DB_PORT'` when I run it without docker. I haven't tested it with Docker setup though, will let you know a bit later!

Comment: I am guessing your django app isn't containerised? `django-environ` does not do variable expansion when parsing `.env` file while `docker compose` does while passing environment to containers.

Comment: Env vars in the environment attribute in a docker-compose file do not interpolate from an .env file. The .env file will pass the vars to container. Listing them in the environment attribute will essentially take precedence over anything declared in the .env file.